# Elements XII. 16 - exercise left to the reader?

Tags: geometry

In book *XII* of the *Elements* the [16th proposition](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookXII/propXII16.html) shows the construction of an equilateral polygon in two concentric circles so that the polygon is inscribed in the outer circle but doesn't touch the inner circle.

The crucial part is this:

> Now, since LN is parallel to AC, and AC touches the circle EFGH, therefore LN does not touch the circle EFGH. Therefore LD and DN are far from touching the circle EFGH.

> If, then, we fit into the circle ABCD straight lines equal to the straight line LD and placed repeatedly, then there is inscribed in the circle ABCD an equilateral polygon with an even number of sides which does not touch the lesser circle EFGH.

I don't see where Euclid proves that placing the *LD* line(segment) repeatedly along the outer circle results in a polygon. Is it proved somewhere earlier? I didn't see a reference to this particular claim in the text. Or is this left as an (easy) exercise for the reader?

The closest proposition is in *[III. 30](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII30.html)*, but that only proves that one can always bisect a circumference.

Comment: Arc $LD$ is constructed "bisecting the circumference BAD, bisecting the half of it, and doing this repeatedly", hence it is a submultiple $1/2^n$ of the circle.